# Baixar site com php

Tags: php

boa noite, estou aprendendo a programar, e por isso estou tentando fazer uma cópia de um site com sistema de login, senha, e varios usuários, estou tentando baixar porque é uma das maneiras que eu particularmente uso pra aprender e que funciona comigo, eu fico observando o código, vendo sua funcionalidade e fuçando pra aprender melhor, existe alguma maneira de baixar um site pronto com php e tals?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está perceptível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Baixar um site não é possivel, mas é possível conseguir códigos prontos em muitas linguagens no [GuitHub](https://github.com).

Com respeito ao código PHP, é necessário compreender que o PHP é uma linguagem Server Side, ou seja, é executada pelo servidor e pode retornar o resultado em Client Side, como por exemplo em HTML. Por ser executado pelo servidor, não é possível ter acesso ao código fonte.

Answer (score 3):

Baixar site é impossível, isso seria decorrente de uma **falha de segurança**, pois daria a você acesso dados internos, como **configuração de acesso ao banco de dados**, **etc..**

Você pode baixar apenas baixar os arquivo gerados pelo script, no formato **HTML**, **imagens**, **Javascript**, **etc...**

Você pode achar scripts prontos.

Comment: pow @Wéllingthon M. de Souza, nada é impossible, ele pode usar o wget e baixar todo o conteúdo de um diretório (https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/Wget-Baixando-sites-inteiros)

Comment: Mas não ó código PHP rs

Comment: sim, é, baixa tudo que tem na pasta informada como ela estiver no disco do servidor, já usei aqui, funcionou blzura

Comment: mas @Mikaela Kleinkauf, se eu souber que vc baixou um site meu, ririri, vc vai ser processada por ataque aos direitos autorais, eim...

Comment: @ArmandoMarquesSobrinho desse modo, com um simples `ctrl + s` você também consegue fazer... mas os arquivos que rodam no servidor, que são processados, você só consegue baixar com acesso via ftp

Comment: Opa @MarceloBoni quando precisei usei o wget segundo a dica do vvl e funcionou redondinho.

Comment: Se vc está começando a programar, aprenda as coisa mais básicas. Sistema de login eh mais complicado pra quem está começando pois se o código for "fraco" qq um mais entendido pode burlar seu sistema.

Comment: Não existe nenhum método pra baixar um "site" ou script PHP a menos que o servidor forneça o arquivo como texto plano, não passando pelo interpretador do PHP. Se isso fosse possível, desafio você a pegar qualquer site wordpress e baixar o arquivo wp-config.php e ver a senha.  O que recomendo ao autor da pergunta é procurar por projetos Open Source.

Comment: não pretendo roubar  nenhum site hahahah, o HTML eu ja peguei bem os conceitos, eu tava querendo baixar justamente pra aprender o PHP, ai me falaram que seria bom pegar algum site com login e senha, pra ver como é feito e entender, não procuro nada com banco de dados e tals, não quero a senha de nada hahahah, eu acho que vou pela ideia do Open Source hahahah, muito obrigada gente ^^

Answer (score 3):

Você não precisa baixar um site "qualquer" pra aprender esses conceitos. Existem vários sistemas prontos, disponíveis gratuitamente, que já tem essa funcionalidade incorporada e que você pode estudar.

**Dois exemplos:**

1. [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) é um Framework PHP que já traz essa
   [funcionalidade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication).
2. [WordPress](https://wordpress.org/) é um CMS que implementa isso de uma forma
   [totalmente diferente](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_signon/).

Você pode baixar os sistemas e ler a documentação pra ver como funcionam.